How to see the app name in journalctl lines?
If I run
journalctl -u app_1 -u app_2 -f

I see the lines:
Jun 07 12:29:31 server app[194430]:   2024-06-07T12:29:31.257154Z ERROR custom_error
Jun 07 12:53:33 server app[194430]: another message
Jun 07 12:53:33 server app[158501]:   2024-06-07T12:53:33.288144Z ERROR custom_error
Jun 07 15:04:03 server app[158501]: another message

As you can see there are two different app[194430] and app[158501].
Is there a way to see the app name instead of that number?
